# how can build SQL query for below mentioned problem?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have below mentioned two data sets, Table A and Table B, and I am trying to get to Table C as output dataset using Table A and TableB, can you help me with SQL query to come up wit this out put.  I am mainly trying to calculate DueAmount column in TableC, and logic to derive this column is mentioned in Calculation column

Data Screenshot:
[TableA, TableB and Output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4k6e.png)

I thought about trying the logic in which Table A can be expanded to multiple row for each period , and then join TableA with TableB, but I am looking for some logic which will be more efficient for large number of ID's.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: What does K5 and E5 mean? Can you confirm your output table has the same number of rows as TableB?

Comment: updated the picture and calculation column for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

The below will generate the results desired:

```
SELECT p.PeriodId, CASE WHEN b.BAmt < a.AAmt THEN 0 ELSE b.BAmt - a.AAmt END AS DueAmt
FROM (SELECT PeriodId FROM TableA UNION SELECT PeriodId FROM TableB) p
CROSS APPLY (SELECT SUM(Amount) AS AAmt FROM TableA WHERE PeriodId <= p.PeriodId) a
CROSS APPLY (SELECT SUM(Amount) AS BAmt FROM TableB WHERE PeriodId <= p.PeriodId) b
```